# React Native Record in 60 fps

Tags: react-native, camera

I've been working with `expo-camera` to record video in my React Native app. However, after going through the documentation I cannot find any way to set the frame rate. Is there any way to shoot video at 60+ fps with `expo-camera` or some other library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VisionCamera can achieve 60fps video recording and also many other features.